# Does @csrf_exempt decorator make django view unsafe?

Tags: django, security

I am wondering in what circumstances using @csrf_exempt decorator does not open door to possible XSS exploits?

To give a concrete example, here is the view that I've written, which adds a simple ajax Like count to blog posts:

```
@csrf_exempt
def like(request):
    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.POST.get('user')
        lu= request.user 
        post_id = int(request.POST.get('post_id'))
        try:
            liked_blog = Blog.objects.get(id = post_id)
        except:
            liked_blog = None  

        if BlogLike.objects.filter(liker=request.user.id, blog=post_id):

            liked_blog.likes -=1
            liked_blog.save()
            BlogLike.objects.filter(blog=post_id, liker=request.user.id).delete()


        else:            
            liked_blog.likes +=1
            liked_blog.save()
            newliker = BlogLike(blog=post_id, liker=request.user.id)
            newliker.save()          



    args['likes'] = str(liked_blog.likes)
    return render(request, 'ajax_like.html', args)
```

the ajax part:

```
$(function(){
$('#like').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/blog/like/",
               data: {
               'post_id': $(this).attr('name'), 
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
               },
               success: likeSuccess,
               dataType: 'html'
                }); 
    });

});
function likeSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#like_count').html(data);
}
```

I added @csrf_exempt to get rid of an annoying error about CSRF. 
So I'm wondering in circumstances like here, how the site can be volnurable by adding @csrf_exempt?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem in mind? StackOverflow is probably not the best site discussion site for which this question will be good for. Please feel free to edit the question to include more details.

Comment: @miki725 I made the question code-specific. Thanks for your note.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable csrf, then any site would be able to increment your counter. Since your view does not do anything special, I don't think it is of particular security importance (but you never know when it comes to security). If the only reason you disabled csrf is to avoid csrf errors then there is actually a very easy fix. Just include the code from the gist and it will work like magic...

https://gist.github.com/miki725/3892061

By the way I compiled the code from official django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/).

**Edit:**

This fix only works for jquery however there are similar fixes in other js frameworks such as angular, etc